Why doesn't the number density of electrons increase with increase in temprature?
It is said that for some increase in temperature of a conductor there exists only some decrease in the average relaxation time of electrons in that conductor due to increase of their thermal velocities.
But increasing temperature should cause more electrons to jump out in the conduction band to conduct the current then why do we say that the number density of a material remains constant even after changes in temperature?

No new electrons emerge with increasing temperature - some of them move from conduction to valence band, so the number of conduction electrons increases, whereas the number of valence electrons decreases, while the total number of electrons remains the same - reflecting the conservation of charge and matter (which holds in non-relativistic setting).
This is not unlike exciting an atom to a higher energy state - its state changes, but not the number of electrons... unless the atom becomes ionized, in which case it transforms into an ion. Likewise, a metal can be ionized via photoeffect.

At first, in most conductors like metals the valence and conduction band overlap together. There is significant band gap difference occur at semiconductor, insulators.
Now, on increasing the temperature on such conductors, the electrons (which can move freely over lattice) get thermal energy and move in random manner. This random motion decrease the conduction of electrons in one particular direction, on applying potential difference between conductor ends.
